# Run Promises in a specific order

Tags: javascript

I have 5 promises I want to put in a specific order. But I have struggled a lot with finding a way to put them in the correct order. 
I have tried the following, resulting in a order of (1-2)-5-(3-4) instead of (1-2)-(3-4)-5, or (3-4)-(1-2)-5 (also OK). So the 5th comes too early, it should come last. I have tried to put 1+2+3+4 in an array/list as you can see below, and then creating the 5th promise, telling it to wait for the execution of 1-4. But the order turnes out incorrectly, as said... Any ideas?

```
this.promises.push(PROMISE1.then(() => {

    **Code for PROMISE 1**

    this.promises.push(PROMISE2.then(() => {

                        **Code for PROMISE 2**

                      })
   );
}));

this.promises.push(PROMISE3.then(() => {

    **Code for PROMISE 3**

        this.promises.push(PROMISE4).then(() => {

                        **Code for PROMISE 4**

                      })
        );
    }));

Promise.all(this.promises).then(() => {

      **Code for PROMISE 5**

   });
```

Comment: It happens because at the time of execution of Promise.all(this.promises), your array contains only PROMISE1 and PROMISE2, promises 3 and 4 are not added to this.promises yet and do not affect all behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing in the callback for each promise, return the inner promise.

```
var promises = [];

promises.push(method1().then(() => { return method2().then(() => { } });
promises.push(method3().then(() => { return method4().then(() => { } });
Promise.all(promises).then(() => { ... });
```

Here's a working sample:

```js
function delay(time, name) {
   console.log("running", name);
   return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time));
}

var promises = [];

promises.push(delay(1000, "1").then(() => {
    console.log("1 inner");
    return delay(500, "1 inner").then(() => console.log("1 inner most"));
}));

promises.push(delay(250, "2").then(() => {
    console.log("2 inner");
    return delay(1000, "2 inner").then(() => console.log("2 inner most"));
}));

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log("all done!"));
```

Comment: It's a pretty complex application, so the simplest example I can do is the one in the question post. I have a link to the project on GitHub if that helps?